# Take n elements from a collection

Tags: jquery, html

I am sure it's not a specific jQuery question but I use it for realizing my task so I will describe what I need in context of jQuery and HTML.
I have a HTML page with divs that are generated by the server. They look like

```
<div class="image"><img src="image1.png" /></div>
<div class="image"><img src="image2.png" /></div>
...
<div class="image"><img src="imagen.png" /></div>
```

The count of the divs is variable and can be, for example, 40-50.
I take a collection of them with something like this: `images = jQuery('.image');`
Now I need to take every 9 divs from the collection and place them in a newly created container, for example, like this:

```
<div class="container1">
<div class="image"><img src="image1.png" /></div>
<div class="image"><img src="image2.png" /></div>
<div class="image"><img src="image3.png" /></div>
...
<div class="image"><img src="image9.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Then I need to take next 9 elements and place them in a similar newly created div, like this:

```
<div class="container2">
<div class="image"><img src="image10.png" /></div>
<div class="image"><img src="image11.png" /></div>
<div class="image"><img src="image12.png" /></div>
...
<div class="image"><img src="image18.png" /></div>
</div>
```

This way I need to take all elements and place them in newly created containers. In the end I will have a couple of containers holding 9 elements each. The last container, obviously, can have less elements if the total amount of image divs is not a multiple of 9.
I am not asking for a complete solution, but I need to realize the principle of taking each 9 elements from a collection.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FIX !**

.. thank's for all the reviews. This working version is built on approaches by [patrick dw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/patrick-dw). Hope this helps..

```
var images = jQuery('.image');
for(i = 0; i < images.length / 9; i++) {
 jQuery('<div />', {
   id: 'conainter_' + i,
   html: images.slice(i*9, i*9+9)
 }).appendTo('body');
}
```

*even though my initially answer was only meant to be a hint ;)*

Comment: +1 This is a more complete solution than mine, but I would prefer `slice(0,8)` to `find`. Good to know about `detach` :)

Comment: This is wrong for a few reasons. 1) Using `.find()` has no affect on the items found by the selector. 2) Using `.detach()` doesn't remove them from the jQuery object so you'll have an infinite loop. 3) You're appending all of them to the same container, so you're ending up with effectively the same as the original. You might as well just do `jQuery('.image').appendTo('#container')`.

Comment: you're right patrick :) fixed the loop. You could use a `for-loop` instead of `while` and pass use it for the container id. Btw: `detach` works fine for me.

Comment: @pex - You're still just appending them to a static container instead of creating new containers for every 9 (not 8) `.image` elements. Also, you're removing the `image` class. OP didn't want this. Not to mention that you're running the same selector several times. Sorry. :o( EDIT: Detach works now since your solution relies on them being removed from the DOM instead of from the jQuery object. But it isn't necessary. You could just remove the class, and do a direct `.appendTo('#container')`.

Comment: @patrick hopefully this suits you more.. thank's for your help!

Comment: pex - Looks much better. Just remove the `#` from the ID since it is an invalid character (easy mistake, comes from typing too may jQuery selectors). And of course it's not about what suits me. Even hints shouldn't contain infinite loops and redundant selectors. This looks very nice though. :o)

Comment: @patrick hopefully the last fix for tody ^^ - next time i'll check my hints for possible infinite loops

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work fine.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kQ4Vp/ *(I changed the example to remove the `+  (i / 9)` from the container class to more easily style the container showing the result.)*

```
var $images = $('.image'); // get all the elements with the class "image"
var i = 0; // Start counter at 0. It will increment by 9: 0, 9, 18, etc.

 // Run a loop while "i" is less than the total number of images
while ( i < $images.length ) {

     // Create a new div, giving it a class "container0" "container1" etc.
    $('<div>', {'class':'container' +  (i / 9)})

            // Take a slice of the images from the current "i" thru "i + 9"
            //  so, 0-9, 9-18, 18-27, etc. and append them to the new div
        .append( $images.slice(i, i + 9) )

        .appendTo( 'body' );  // Append the new div to the body (or wherever)

    i += 9; // Increment "i" by 9
}
```

**EDIT:** Changed it to use a `while` instead of a `do/while`. Not sure why I had it that way at first.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `slice` and `end` to good effect:

```
var pars = $('p');
pars.slice(0,4);
// do something with it, such as append()
pars.end().slice(5,9);
// do something with this slice, etc
```

If `pars.slice` returns an empty array, you're done.

Answer (score 1):

First off, this code assumes all the divs are siblings of one another in the DOM.

```
var $images = $(".image"),
    len = 9;

for (var x = 0, y = 1; x < $images.length; x += len, y++) {
    $images.slice(x, x + len).wrapAll('<div class="container' + y + '" />');
}
```

Basically, you retrieve all the `.image` elements, then you set the length of each container.

Then a loop is started that starts uses `x` to count the number of elements, and `y` to count the number of groups.

Last, slice is called on those elements for each group, and wraps a div with the class "container`y`".

Comment: If it's just about wrapping, this is a smart one!